# JQuery: select by id, но не в странице, а в элементе

Tags: jquery, typescript, css-selectors

Господа.
У меня такая конструкция на странице:
два вложденных `div`'а:

```html
<div id="externalDiv">
  <div id="internalDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Я хочу сделать следующее:

1) Сначала вырезать внешний `div` из страницы.
И записать его в переменную `template`.

2) потом вставить его на страницу 3 раза, каждый раз добавляя другой текст во внутренний `div`

Первую часть сделать просто:

```
this.template = $("#externalDiv");  
$("#externalDiv").remove();
```

А теперь мне надо взять переменную, и к ней применить JQuery - селектор.

То есть, если бы ЭТА ШТУКА уже была на странице - я бы написал

```
$("#internalDiv").text("Текст 1");
```

Но как это сделать не в пределах страницы, а в передах переменной `this.template`?

Спасибо за советы!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: например find, или вторым параметром передавать в качестве контекста текущий элемент

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!